# How to get totals in this database

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I have a database.

```
-----------------------
|   code   |  value  |
-----------------------
| shipping |  20     |
| unique   |   4     |
| shipping |  25     |
| unique   |   6     |
-----------------------

totals "shipping" = 45 (should)
```

I mean how to get the `totals` of each `order_id` based `code = " shipping "` . I use database `opencart`. Thank you.

Comment: Opencart is the DB or `mysql`? I thought opencart was frameworkish..

Comment: `SELECT code, sum(value) as total  FORM table GROUP BY order_id, code` OR Without Order_id `SELECT code, sum(value) as total  FORM table GROUP BY  code`

Comment: _totals "shipping" = 45 (should)_ is not valid, cause order id is different

Comment: it does not refer to the order _id

Comment: add a where clause for it.

Comment: @MochammadDannysetyawan "**"it does not refer to the order _id"**  so why are you asking **"I mean how to get the `totals` of each `order_id` based `code = " shipping "`"** ?!

Comment: SELECT code, sum(value) as total FORM table WHERE code = 'shipping' GROUP BY code

Comment: Do you want total value of shipping or each order_id?. I think order_id will be unique it wont repeat. If you said clearly, i could help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT order_id, SUM(value) AS Total
FROM your_table
WHERE code = "shipping"
GROUP BY order_id
```

Comment: I mean get a total based code = ' shipping ' is not based order_id

Comment: I think its only the shipping not `order_id`.

Comment: It's wasn't clear to me (and it still isn't) but I've updated the answer to match the OP question, tks!

Comment: @MochammadDannysetyawan You need the `order_id`, otherwise it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it using the `sum` method of MySql. Try the below Query.

group by your unique field and sum the value.

```
SELECT code, sum(value) as total FORM table WHERE code = 'shipping' GROUP BY order_id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT
  code,
       SUM(value) AS value
FROM
    order_table
WHERE code="shipping" GROUP BY code
```

Comment: he need total value not each row value

Comment: its fetching total  value only.When we run this code the answer is 45 for shipping

Comment: without group by how it give output 45 ?

Comment: Oh I forgot to add that.Thanx

Comment: If its looking perfect then you can do me a favour and upvote my answer.Thanx in advance

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113365/discussion-between-jothi-and-aarju-mishra).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use sum and group by to get the cost for each code.

try this

```
SELECT code, sum(value) as total FORM table WHERE code = 'shipping' GROUP BY code
```